# create_image is not moving horizontally when im clicking arrow key

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to create a egg catching game and the image is not moving when i clicked the arrow keys
i tried using this code and it's not working

```
catcher_width = 100
catcher_height = 100
catcher_startx = 800 / 2 - catcher_width / 2
catcher_starty = 500 - catcher_height - 20
catcher_startx2 = catcher_startx + catcher_width
catcher_starty2 = catcher_starty + catcher_height

basket = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\Mike\Downloads\\basket.png') 
catcher = c.create_image(catcher_startx, catcher_starty,  image=basket)

def move_left(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    if x1 > 0:
        c.move(catcher, -20, 0)

def move_right(event):
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = c.coords(catcher)
    if x2 < 800:
        c.move(catcher, 20, 0)

c.bind("<Left>", move_left)
c.bind("<Right>", move_right)

c.focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The coordinates in the canvas `.move` method are absolute, not relative.  You need `c.move(catcher, x1-20, y1)`

Comment: @TimRoberts that is not correct. `move` adds the x or y value to the existing coordinates.

Comment: I see that now; the documentation is worded quite vaguely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code throws errors which tell you exactly what the problem is. `c.coords(catcher)` returns only a single x,y pair rather than two pairs. When I replace that code with `c.bbox(catcher)` then the image moves when I press the arrow keys.